# First letter of every word gets capitalized after saving to mysql using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to using Flask+SQLAlchemy to build a rest api. I am new to this. I just encounter a wired problem. First letter of every word get capitalized after the words saved to the mysql. The code is below:

```
@app.route('/gifs')
def crawlHome():
    url = "http://domain.com.cn"
    newgif = Gif(url)
    db.session.add(newgif)
    db.session.commit() 



class Gif(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "gifs"
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(200))
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url.title()
    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'uid' : self.uid,
            'url' : self.url
        }
```

And the saved url is like this: `"Http://Domain.Com.Cn"`. Why? I am very new to python. So, please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Check if `'Gif(url)'` is returning an empty string!

Comment: It's already been saved in the database. Of course it's not empty.

Comment: How did you find that the saved data is in *CamelCase*? From MySQL Client or using your scripting language?

Comment: I see it in my database. Using command line: select * from gifs.

Comment: Can you update your answer with yout `Gif` model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is capitalized because you are using the [title](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) function from the string built-in type.

```
>>> "http://domain.com.cn".title()
'Http://Domain.Com.Cn'
```

You need to replace `self.url = url.title()` by `self.url = url` in the `Gif` model `__init__` function.

Comment: I c. Should try to figure it out from there.